# Execute multiple switch cases

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    switch num := 75; { //num is not a constant
    case num < 50:
        fmt.Printf("%d is lesser than 50\n", num)   
    case num < 100:
        fmt.Printf("%d is lesser than 100\n", num)  
    case num < 60:
        fmt.Printf("%d is lesser than 60", num)
    case num < 200:
        fmt.Printf("%d is lesser than 200", num)
    }
}
```

If I want to execute the next case I can use `fallthrough`, but it won't check condition against the case. I need to check the condition: I want to continue the switch case as normal, even after it met one case.

I would like to check the next case condition also with `fallthrough`, is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, you cannot check subsequent `case` conditions using `fallthrough`, since `fallthrough` is unconditional and forces the next case to be executed. That's its purpose.

---

Long answer: you can still use `fallthrough`: if you look closely in this case you only need to **reorder your cases** in a way which makes sense. Note that this is not always true though.

```
switch num := 75; {
case num < 50:
    fmt.Printf("%d is less than 50\n", num)
    fallthrough // Any number less than 50 will also be less than 60
case num < 60:
    fmt.Printf("%d is less than 60\n", num)
    fallthrough // Any number less than 60 will also be less than 100
case num < 100:
    fmt.Printf("%d is less than 100\n", num)      
    fallthrough // Any number less than 100 will also be less than 200
case num < 200:
    fmt.Printf("%d is less than 200\n", num)
}
```

This way you can safely use `fallthrough`, because since the conditions are correctly ordered you already know that if `num` passes one of them, then it is obviously also going to pass every subsequent condition.

Moreover, if you actually don't want to simply `fallthrough` to the next case, but you want to execute another case, you can add a labeled case and use `goto` to jump right to it.

```
switch num := 75; {
firstCase:
    fallthrough
case num < 50:
    fmt.Println("something something\n")
case num < 100:
    fmt.Printf("%d is less than 100\n", num)  
    goto firstCase
}
```

Take a look at the Go GitHub wiki [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Switch#fall-through) for more information.

---

**By the way**, if you are using a `switch` statement and need to force some unnatural case handling then you are probably doing the whole thing wrong: consider using another approach, like some nested `if` statements for example.

Comment: While reordering the cases works here, the general solution is to rewrite the switch statement as a series of if statements.